# Perl socket connection

Tags: perl, sockets

Is it possible to create a socket connection to an open port on an end device.

If the connection drops print something?

I have seen a few examples but they require a server type script and a client, just looking for a client.

Thanks

Comment: If I say connect to port 23 for example, will the telnet server stop working?  I just tested this sokething with port 80 and the script was running after I killed it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has sockets built right into it. You just need to load the standard `Socket.pm` module to get the constants you need.

The *perlipc* manpage tells you all about this. There are many higher-level modules that get at this more easily than the builtins, however. Some are even standard.

Here’s a CLI example:

```
% perl -MIO::Socket::INET -E '$him = new IO::Socket::INET "localhost:daytime" // die; print while <$him>'
Tue Jun 28 08:17:13 2011
```

Comment: Is `0` a valid return from `IO::Socket::INET->new`? It doesn't seem like it would be.

Comment: @Axeman, nope. Constructors should always return true. `||` suffices.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the module [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Socket/INET.pm), http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/perl-tcp-udp-socket-programming/

Comment: I'm a fan of [Socket::Class](http://p3rl.org/Socket::Class) where the interface is not so *baroque*.

Comment: Perl, so as usual TMTOWTDI ;)

Answer (score 0):

A variation of this might fit your need:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant 
    { SOCKET_ERROR_MESSAGE => 'Some socket error message right here!'
    , YOU_WANT_TO          => 1
    };

use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket::INET;

@ARGV = qw<server.domain.tld 8080> unless @ARGV;

sub handle_server_message {
    ...
}

my $sel 
    = IO::Select->new(
      IO::Socket::INET->new( 
      PeerAddr => shift
    , PeerPort => shift
    ));

# block until the server sends something that can be read.
while ( my ( $sock ) = $sel->can_read ) { 
    # you could just do this with $sock->eof...
    if ( $sock->error and $sock->eof ) {
        die MY_ERROR_MESSAGE if YOU_WANT_TO;
        print MY_ERROR_MESSAGE;
    }
    else { 
        handle_server_message( $sock );
    }
}
```